# TS2322: Type Element is not assignable to type 'boolean'

Tags: typescript

I'm new with TypeScript, try to  type my const `dialogFuncMap` but recieve an Error (on comments below).
Why i get this error, if type of state is `boolean` ? How to fix it? (except any)

state:

```
const [displayBasic, setDisplayBasic] = useState<boolean>(false);
```

function:

```
const dialogFuncMap: Record<string, boolean> = {
        'displayBasic': setDisplayBasic, // TS2322: Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
    }
```

Comment: `setDisplayBasic` is a function, it's even named as a function. `dialogFuncMap` is a dictionary from strings to booleans. Now you are trying to provide a function where you said you'd provide a boolean — and the language points this inconsistency out.

Answer (score 1):

The type of displayBasic is boolean, while setDisplayBasic sets the value of the state. To fix this put displayBasic where you have setDisplayBasic.

Answer (score 0):

setDisplayBasic is a function, the boolean is  displayBasic. Your code should look like this:

```js
const dialogFuncMap: Record<string, boolean> = {
        'displayBasic': displayBasic
    }
```

Comment: this is how i solved if  const dialogFuncMap: Record<string, typeof setDisplayBasic> = {
        'displayBasic': setDisplayBasic,
    }

Comment: if only boolean it cause an Error too